# Why is the enemy not moving?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have a problem everything works except when the enemy is supposed to move right it says theres an error a line, the very last line.
It started when I made my bullet; before that everything worked fine.
I dont know why its doing it, but I cant figure it out; it's weird. Please help thank you very much and please dont judge my readability because i just started writing code.heres the message
File "E:\Code\Space Invaders.py", line 106, in enemy.setx(x)

```
 import turtle
 import os

 wn = turtle.Screen()
 wn.bgcolor("black")
 wn.title('Space Invasders')

 border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
 border_pen.speed(0)
 border_pen.color('white')
 border_pen.penup()
 border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
 border_pen.pendown()
 border_pen.pensize(3)
 for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
 border_pen.hideturtle()

 player = turtle.Turtle()
 player.color('blue')
 player.shape('triangle')
 player.penup()
 player.speed(0)
 player.setposition(0, -250)
 player.setheading(90)
 playerspeed = 15

 enemy = turtle.Turtle()
 enemy.color('red')
 enemy.shape('circle')
 enemy.penup()
 enemy.speed(0)
 enemy.setposition(-200, 250)

 enemyspeed = 2

 bullet = turtle.Turtle()
 bullet.color('yellow')
 bullet.shape('triangle')
 bullet.penup()
 bullet.speed(0)
 bullet.setheading(90)
 bullet.shapesize(0.5, 0.5)
 bullet.setposition(player.xcor(), player.ycor() + 10)
 bullet.ht()
 bulletspeed = 20

 player_alive = True

 if enemy.xcor() == player.xcor() and enemy.ycor() == player.ycor():
    player_alive = False


 def fire():

        x = player.xcor()
        y = player.ycor() + 10
        bullet.st()
        bullet.setposition(x, y)

 def right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    if x > 280:
        x = 280
    player.setx(x)


 def left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed
    if x < -280:
        x = - 280
    player.setx(x)


 wn.onkey(left, "Left")
 wn.onkey(right, "Right")
 wn.onkey(fire, "space")
 wn.listen()
 wn.mainloop()

 while player_alive == True:
    x = enemy.xcor()
    x += enemyspeed
    enemy.setx(x) #this line is messed up
```

Comment: What happens when you change x = - 280 to x = -280? Not sure why you have a space there

Comment: put a comment on the line it is complaining about and give us the exact error message

Comment: i can't reproduce the described behavior. Can you post the full error message?

Comment: @KILLtheWEEZEL While `x = - 5` "should not" have a space between the `-` and the `5`, according to standard coding patterns, I believe it is technically ok to do so. Going to an online python REPL shows that it is not a gauranteed error - at least some compilers accept it, and I expect that most do. The **OP** does need to include the **exact error message**, though, and should also add a additional sentence that indicates the exact line of code being referenced, with that line duplicated as a single line code block.

Comment: I counted lines and came up with line 75 being `player.setx(x)
` in the `def left():` code block.  Is this correct?

Comment: BTW "Space Invaders" is misspelled ;)

Comment: i had the line wrong SherylHohman

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem:

```
wn.mainloop()

while player_alive == True:
    x = enemy.xcor()
    x += enemyspeed
    enemy.setx(x) #this line is messed up
```

The `mainloop()` method should be the last call in your program -- calling it turns over event handling to tkinter's event loop.  No code following it will execute until the turtle world is closed down.

For an immediate fix, I suggest your move your `mainloop()` call until after your `while` loop:

```
while player_alive:
    x = enemy.xcor()
    x += enemyspeed
    enemy.setx(x)

wn.mainloop()
```

For a long term fix, I suggest that you not use a `while` loop but rather an `ontimer()` event.